# http rest api delete entries in geode region

Tags: gemfire, http-verbs, geode

I have setup the Geode rest API and can run get and queries, via Chrome, on a region for example:

`http://localhost:8080/gemfire-api/v1/items`

When I try and delete entries in a region according to [Developing REST Applications](https://geode.apache.org/docs/guide/10/rest_apps/develop_rest_apps.html) by using the following endpoint:

`DELETE /gemfire-api/v1/{region}`

For example:

`http://localhost:7070/gemfire-api/v1/items`

Can you tell me how to run the example in Chrome, and delete the entries please? I simply want to be able to run

`http://localhost:8080/gemfire-api/v1/items/delete`

but instead I am getting

`{"cause":"Key (delete) does not exist for region (items) in cache!"}`

Answer (score 1):

You are going to need to use ajax. The `DELETE` is talking about the HTTP verb you need and not that you need to add it to the URL.

Have your delete function execute this code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost:7070/gemfire-api/v1/items,
    type: 'DELETE',
    data: {item:item}, //<-----this should have to be an object of your item type.
    contentType:'application/json', 
    dataType: 'text',                
    success: function(result) {...}, // <---update this with a callback
    error: function(result){...}// <---update this with a callback
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Via the browser Chrome you can use an extension like [Postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop)

It will allow you to send request with any verb, so you could simply test the request before using them within whatever you do, your website for example)

GET (like when you simply type the url in the browser and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>)

POST (like when you submit a form)

DELETE (the one you want)

PUT (another verb widely used usually for update an existing object)

Illustration for use : 
[image]